# Ansible - how to run a script on a relative path

Tags: ansible

My question is why can I not use a relative path to specify a bash script to run?

I have a ansible file structure following [best practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout).

My directory structure for this role is:

```
.
├── files
│   └── install-watchman.bash
└── tasks
    └── main.yml
```

and the main.yml includes this:

```
- name: install Watchman
  shell: "{{ role_path }}/files/install-watchman.bash"

- name: copy from files dir to target home dir
  copy:
    src: files/install-watchman.bash
    dest: /home/vagrant/install-watchman.bash
    owner: vagrant
    group: vagrant
    mode: 0744

- name: install Watchman
  shell: files/install-watchman.bash
```

I would expect all three commands to work, but in practice the third one fails:

```
TASK [nodejs : install Watchman] ***********************************************
changed: [machine1]

TASK [nodejs : copy from files dir to target home dir] ********
changed: [machine1]

TASK [nodejs : install Watchman] ***********************************************
fatal: [machine1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "files/install-watchman.bash", "delta": "0:00:00.002997", "end": "2019-01-27 16:01:50.093530", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-01-27 16:01:50.090533", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: files/install-watchman.bash: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: files/install-watchman.bash: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
    to retry, use: --limit @/vagrant/ansible/site.retry
```

(If it helps, this is the version info for ansible:)

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ ansible --version
ansible 2.7.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/vagrant/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put together a test of this to see: https://github.com/farrellit/ansible-demonstrations/tree/master/shell-cwd

It has convinced me that the short answer is probably, *ansible roles' `shell` tasks will by default have the working directory of the playbook that include that role*.

It basically comes down to a role like this ( the rest of that dir is tooling to make it run):

```
- shell: pwd
  register: shellout
- debug: var=shellout.stdout
- shell: pwd
  args:
    chdir: "{{role_path}}"
  register: shellout2
- debug: var=shellout2.stdout
```

This has shown:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [shelldir : command] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [shelldir : debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "shellout.stdout": "/code"
}

TASK [shelldir : command] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [shelldir : debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "shellout2.stdout": "/code/roles/shelldir"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

That the current working directory for roles is not `role_path`.  In my case it is the role of the playbook that invoked the task.  It might be something else in the case of an included playbook or tasks file from a different directory (I'll leave that as an exercise for you, if you care).  I set that execution to run from `/tmp`, so I don't think it would matter the current working directory of the shell that ran `ansible-playbook`.

Comment: Confirmed: the pwd for main.yml is the directory of the playbook that invoked it. I managed to make it a relative path by using `shell: roles/rolename/files/install-watchman.bash`. I can't find a reference to explain _why_ it is this way, but you comment gives the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Shell will execute the command on the remote. You have copied the script to `/home/vagrant/install-watchman.bash` on your remote. Therefore you have to use that location for executing on the remote as well.

```
- name: install Watchman
  shell: /home/vagrant/install-watchman.bash
```

a relative path will work as well, if your ansible user is the user "vagrant"

```
- name: install Watchman
  shell: install-watchman.bash
```

Side note:

I would recommend to use `command` instead of `shell` whenever possible: [shell vs command Module](https://blog.confirm.ch/ansible-modules-shell-vs-command/)

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'have to use that location'? The first command in my set of three used different location linked to the role, and seemed to work fine.